# Why is Keras LSTM on CPU three times faster than GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I use [this notebook from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/sbongo/for-beginners-tackling-toxic-using-keras) to run LSTM neural network.

I had started training of neural network and I saw that it is too slow. It is almost three times slower than CPU training.

- `CPU perfomance:` 8 min per epoch;
- `GPU perfomance:` 26 min per epoch.

After this I decided to find answer in [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972015/keras-lstm-on-cpu-faster-than-gpu) and I applied a `CuDNNLSTM` *(which runs only on GPU)* instead of `LSTM`.

Hence, GPU perfomance became **only 1 min per epoch** and accuracy of model decreased on 3%.

**Questions:**

1) Does somebody know why GPU works slower than CPU in the classic `LSTM` layer? I do not understand why this happens.

2) Why when I use `CuDNNLSTM` instead of `LSTM`, training become much more faster and the accuracy of the model decrease?

P.S.:

`My CPU:` Intel Core i7-7700 Processor (8M Cache, up to 4.20 GHz)

`My GPU:` nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (4 GB)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guessing it's just a different, better implementation and, if the implementation is different, you shouldn't expect identical results.

In general, efficiently implementing an algorithm on a GPU is *hard* and getting maximum performance requires architecture-specific implementations. Therefore, it wouldn't be surprising if an implementation specific to Nvidia's GPUs had enhanced performance versus a general implementation for GPUs. It also wouldn't be surprising that Nvidia would sink significantly more resources into accelerating their code for their GPUs versus than would a team working on a general CNN implementation.

The other possibility is that the data type used on the backend has changed from double- to single- or even half-precision float. The smaller data types mean you can crunch more numbers faster at the cost of accuracy. For NN applications this is often acceptable because no individual number needs to be especially accurate for the net to produce acceptable results.

Comment: But why LSTM NN on CPU run faster than on GPU? This seems very strange.

Comment: @lemon: It's not uncommon for a CPU to run something faster than a GPU. Remember: serial operations on a GPU are several times slower than a CPU and data gets funneled to a GPU through a thin straw. GPUs overcome these drawbacks by being able to do massively parallel operations. I can't speak to your particular implementation, but, perhaps in your case either the data you're using or the particular match of your general-purpose GPU implementation to your actual hardware is poor.

Comment: From my experience, CPU tends to run faster than GPU on smaller batch sizes. Using CuDNN is always faster.

Comment: @from keras import michael, thank you for the answer! I'll keep this in mind in the future. It is very pleasant to learn the experience of others.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem today and found two things that may be helpful to others (this is a regression problem on a data set with ~2.1MM rows, running on a machine with 4 P100 GPUs):

1. Using the CuDNNLSTM layer instead of the LSTM layer on a GPU machine reduced the fit time from ~13500 seconds to ~400 seconds per epoch.
2. Increasing the batch size (~500 to ~4700) reduced it to ~130 seconds per epoch.

Reducing the batch size has increase loss and val loss, so you'll need to make a decision about the trade offs you want to make.

Answer (score 2):

In Keras, the fast LSTM implementation with CuDNN.

```
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units, input_shape=(len(X_train), len(X_train[0])), return_sequences=True))
```

It can only be run on the `GPU` with the TensorFlow backend.

Comment: Using CuDNNLSTM did not change the situation for me. Even with CuDNNLSTM, the code works 3.5x faster on CPU than on the GPU.

Comment: You have to fine tune the parameters and hyper-parameters for CuDNNLSTM on GPU.